# Programmer gives me an error in programming a big hex file

Tags: atmega, programmer, proteus, hex

I want to download a program into an Atmega128. the programmer which I am using is this ( jamshad ISP -USB ZIF_Socket_Programmer_V5 ).
[image]

The Programmer work correctly for programming one small length hex code but when I want to program a big hex file ( which is tested by Proteus ), The programmer gives me an error and cannot programming the big hex file into the IC.

( I used ISP Connection and i am sure it's connection is correct because i could program micro by a small code and seeing the result on the LCD, but for big hex files the programmer suddenly got an error with several declaration and My PC hanging  Like This:)

[image]
You can get the hex file and Proteus simulator files from this link:

http://filepi.com/i/9zF33M4

Thanks a lot

Comment: Tried to edit your question but it's still unclear. you should add some details about your programmer and how you have connected your programmer to the IC and etc

Comment: Can you at least tell us the error you get?

Comment: one more time -- WHAT ERROR DID YOU GET??

Answer (score 4):

All these Programmers are based on USBASP which is not professional programmer/debugger tools and many parameters e.g. USB cable length make some problems at writing speed and performance. I had same problems with USBASP too. I think the best answer is to say change your programmer and buy a professional one(or a clone version of professional programmers).

Comment: This is not the answer. this is just a suggestion or ... I'm sure he/she can program his/her AVR. absolutely there is a problem. we need to know how he/she is programming his/her AVR.

Comment: That was my experience ,I could programs tiny hex files to MCU with USBASP,but it does not work for large files always correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer, first of all i changed my programmer to a STK 200/300.

Then I changed the software for programming with PROGISP V1.6.6. from this [Link](http://ftp.qrz.ru/pub/hamradio/microchips/progisp166.rar) .

So i used BASCOM and it could not write big HEX Files ( My be because it was Cracked Version !!!).

Anyway I thanks a lot for attentions.